# match two columns and concatenate them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column A and B, i want to concatenate A with B values into c column using formula but need help. The problem is, if column B has more than two colors, then the formula breaks. I'm not quit sure how to fix the formula to support more than 2 colors which will likely happen on my worksheet. Here's the formula:

[image]

```
=IF(AND(A1="---",B1="---"),"---",IF(A1="",CONCATENATE(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)," - ",B1),CONCATENATE(A1," - ",B1)))
```

Comment: In column `C`, do you expect to see `1-green`, `2-grey`, and `3-dark brown`?  Also, what version of Excel?

Comment: yes that is correct. currently using 2007 excel but can be for any version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
C1: =CONCATENATE(MAX($A$1:A1),"-",B1)
```

and fill down.

To account for the "---" entries:

```
C1: =IF(AND(A1="---",B1="---"),"---",CONCATENATE(MAX($A$1:A1),"-",B1))
```

**Edit:** Oh, and if the labels in Column A might not be in a nice numerical sequence, or might be text, you can use:

```
C1: =IF(AND(A1="---",B1="---"),"---",CONCATENATE(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A$1:A1)>0),$A$1:A1),"-",B1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,$A$1:A1))&"-"&B1
```

[image]